# Why doesn't mirth recognize the changes I have made to my channel?

Tags: mirth

I added a database writer destination to a working mirth channel. The destination is not writing to the table like it is supposed to, but it is not generating errors on the dashboard. I'm not really sure how to get it to work.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- changed the name of the table to a non-existing table // Does not generate error, suggesting that it does not even recognize the destination
- validator connector (successful)
- verified username/pw/URL are correct (I even cloned a working database writer from the same channel to try to get it to run)
- removed all filters (in case it was filtering for some reason)
- cloned the same transformer used in another working destination from the same channel
- allowed nulls in the SQL server database in case it was trying to insert nulls
- disabled/enabled channels. Started/restarted mirth. Opened/closed SQL server

I am not really sure what else there is to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChronoFish, doesn't stackexchange discourage cross posting?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it is not an active site yet.  I am trying to garner support so it will be allowed into a beta program.  It would be great if you and other Mirth/HL7 experts would consider contributing.

Comment: @ChronoFish i will be there/am no expert :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to click deploy all channels in the channels menu in order for mirth to launch the modified version of a channel after you make changes to it. Then you may have to start all channels in the dashboard too. That got my channel working

Comment: Actually, you just need to deploy the channel in question, not all of them.

Comment: Depends on which version he's running.  Earlier versions did not let you deploy single channels.  "Deploy All" was the only option